# Validating iFrame when called by Javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, validation, xhtml

I'm trying to validate the following code (Inside a XHTML transitional doc):

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('courseFrameBottomRight').innerHTML = '<iframe  src=\'descriptions/bf_isc.html\' scrolling=\'no\' frameborder=\'0\'></iframe>'" id='onClickTextChange2'><span class="title">Website</span></a>
```

However, this is throwing a huge number of validation errors.

**Example:**

> Line 168, Column 98: character "<" is
>   the first character of a delimiter but
>   occurred as data

The code is modified from a help guide and I don't have experience with the nested quoting or back-slashing going on here. Can someone offer some quick syntax pointers for me to get this valid for 
XHTML Transitional? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try backslashing the '<' '>' signs, like `'\<iframe\>'`

If it doesn't work use the html code instead:

`&gt;` for >
`&lt;` for <

```
&lt;iframe&gt;
```

So the only phrase would be something like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('courseFrameBottomRight').innerHTML = '\<iframe  src=\'descriptions/bf_isc.html\' scrolling=\'no\' frameborder=\'0\'\>\<\/iframe\>'" id='onClickTextChange2'><span class="title">Information Systems Clinic</span></a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('courseFrameBottomRight').innerHTML = '&lt;iframe  src=\'descriptions/bf_isc.html\' scrolling=\'no\' frameborder=\'0\'&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;'" id='onClickTextChange2'><span class="title">Information Systems Clinic</span></a>
```

Or better yet, create a javascript function that does what you need outside the html body code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The &lt; &gt; edits work fine, but the backslashing doesn't seem to. I'm more than happy for this workaround though, even if it isn't pretty. Much obliged!

Comment: Yes. Thanks :) See above comment. Hit return to break the line but it submitted my comment too fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your brackets < > with the escape characters < and > 
Paste your whole iframe string into this page and it will give you the escaped equivalent of it: http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html

That link will give you something like this <iframe  src=\'descriptions/bf_isc.html\' scrolling=\'no\' frameborder=\'0\'></iframe> and that will validate.

edit: I see you got this answer. Just use the above tool to do your escaping for you so it's easy.